# Should std::vector::erase() destroy the element being erased? (instead of the last element)

Tags: c++, stdvector

**Background**

A while back, I ran into some behaviour that I found very strange and seemingly incorrect and I filed a bug report with GCC about it.  You can see the report and the response I got here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47305

(I'm going to replicate most of that here.)

At the time, I didn't understand the answer, but was not a member of StackOverflow and didn't have anyone to ask about it, so I just hacked a work-around and went on.  But recently, I was revisiting this code and I still don't understand the rationale for this not being a bug, so...

**My Question**

In the C++ stdlib distribution included with with my Mac (currently OS X, Darwin 12.2.0 x86_64), the implementation of `std::vector::erase()` from `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/vector.tcc` lines 106-116 is shown here:

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
  typename vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator
  vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
  erase(iterator __position)
  {
    if (__position + 1 != end())
      std::copy(__position + 1, end(), __position);
    --this->_M_impl._M_finish;
    this->_M_impl.destroy(this->_M_impl._M_finish);
    return __position;
  }
```

Note that `destroy()` will be called for the element that is *last* in the
vector prior to the call to this `erase()`, instead of being called for the
element pointed to by `__position`.  I believe this is incorrect -- I think it
should instead call `destroy()` for the element pointed to by `__position`.  For
simple POD types, this isn't that big of a deal, but for classes where the
destructors have side effects (such as smart pointers), it can be critical.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    int m_x;
public:
     MyClass(int x) : m_x(x) { }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        std::cerr << "Destroying with m_x=" << m_x << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<MyClass> testvect;
    testvect.reserve(8);
    testvect.push_back(MyClass(1));
    testvect.push_back(MyClass(2));
    testvect.push_back(MyClass(3));
    testvect.push_back(MyClass(4));
    testvect.push_back(MyClass(5));

    std::cerr << "ABOUT TO DELETE #3:" << std::endl;

    testvect.erase(testvect.begin() + 2);

    std::cerr << "DONE WITH DELETE." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with g++ version 4.2.1 (no command line arguments) on my
Mac, it produces the following when I run it:

```
Destroying with m_x=1
Destroying with m_x=2
Destroying with m_x=3
Destroying with m_x=4
Destroying with m_x=5
ABOUT TO DELETE #3:
Destroying with m_x=5
DONE WITH DELETE.
Destroying with m_x=1
Destroying with m_x=2
Destroying with m_x=4
Destroying with m_x=5
```

Note that the key line after the "ABOUT TO DELETE #3" message shows that the
destructor was actually called for the (copy of the) fifth thing I added.  *Importantly, the
destructor for #3 is never called!!*

It appears that the version of `erase()` that takes a range (two iterators) also
has a similar problem.

***So my question is, am I wrong to expect that the destructor of the element I am erasing from a vector gets called?***  It seems that if you can't count on this, you can't safely use smart pointers in vectors.  Or is this just a bug in the STL vector implementation distributed by Apple?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The destructor for **3** is called, but it now contains a **5**.

Comment: @K-ballo thanks.  but this still seems unsatisfying because if #3 is a smart pointer, the thing it points to won't be cleaned up.

Comment: It will be cleaned up when **#3** is assigned a **#4**. Just change your vector to hold `shared_ptr< MyClass >` and check it out.

Comment: @K-ballo if that were the case, shouldn't the print statement I put in the destructor have printed something for element #3 in my code's output?

Comment: Add print statements to your _copy-constructor_ and _assignment_ operations and you will understand.

Comment: When the third item is "erased", in this case, the stuff from the next higher element is assigned to it.  Copy assignment, basically.  And then the last element, which had nothing to assign to it, gets deleted.  Seems a bit odd to me, as it doesn't seem to allow for vectors of unique_ptrs, but i imagine that's not really an issue in 4.2 (if it's GCC, that's an old version and probably predates C++11).

Comment: @K-ballo doing right now, but I do already understand that these are used to copy the elements 4 and 5.  But I still think regardless of the outcome, the destructor for #3 should get called.

Comment: @Turix: Why?  #3 doesn't get destroyed; it just gets assigned a new value.

Comment: @cHao thanks.  yes, that's exactly what's happening.  And yes, the oddness about vectors of pointers is exactly what I'm concerned about.  Re 4.2, unfortunately, that's still the default version of g++ that comes with Mac OSX.

Comment: @Turix: The destructor for #3 **IS** called, it just happens to contain a #4 now. The default assignment operator does not call the destructor, it just does an element-wise copy. An assignment operator for a smart pointer **would** call the destructor of the _pointed-to_ element.

Comment: @cHao It's an old version of gcc. I'm pretty sure it's llvm-gcc too, which was buggy to begin with and was discontinued quite some time ago. Apparently Apple doesn't bother shipping a remotely up to date C++ compiler, and most people are too lazy to compile from source.

Comment: @Cubic: this code isn't buggy, the code is just fine.

Comment: @Turix: It's not really oddness when you think about it.  In C++03, IIRC, objects in vectors have to be copy-assignable.  That's exactly so something like this can happen.  `operator =` sets #3's state to mirror #4's, and #4's to mirror #5's.  The alternative would be to destroy #3 in place and create a clone of #4 via copy constructor.  Then destroy #4 and clone #5 in its spot.  Then destroy #5.  What does that really get you?  Two extra destructions, that's what.  :)  Now one each of #4 and #5 are destroyed as well as #3.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's great, but has nothing to do with my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `erase` the element containing a **3**, the following elements have to be shifted back to fill the void. Then element **#3** gets assigned what **#4** has, and **#4** gets assigned what **#5** has. The last element, **#5**, is left with whatever value it has since it is about to be deleted anyway.

When the `vector` goes out of scope, you see the remaining 4 elements being destroyed.

If you were to hold *smart pointers* in your `vector`, the resources will be properly freed when the assignment operator is called.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is no problem. In the line

```
std::copy(__position + 1, end(), __position);
```

the deleted element gets overwritten with consecutive elements; if it holds resources that need to be freed, it would do so in its `operator=`.

In C++11, you would want to use move instead of copy; but what you posted is an OK C++03 implementation for `std::vector::erase`.

Answer (score 2):

The destructor only get called for the last element, but the object being erased gets overwritten by assigning from the next element to it. So the assignment operator frees up the old resources. When the type is a smart pointer, that means doing adjusting the reference and, if appropriate, deleting the controlled object.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reasonable point, there are at least two different ways that you could think to implement `erase`:

- destroy element 3, then copy-construct element 3 from 4, then 4 from 5, then destroy 5.
- copy-assign to 3 from 4, then to 4 from 5, then destroy 5.

C++11 introduces a third way to do it:

- move-assign to 3 from 4, then to 4 from 5, then destroy 5.

In fact for `vector::erase` the first way is forbidden by the C++03 standard in 23.2.4.3/4:

> Complexity: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to
>   the number of the elements erased, but the assignment operator of T is
>   called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the
>   vector after the erased elements.

Although this text is designed primarily to indicate the runtime complexity of the operation, you see that it mandates the second implementation. C++11 says the same thing with "move assignment" in place of "assignment".

There's also a more fundamental problem with the first way, which is that in general (although not for `int` and hence not for `MyClass` either), copying can fail. If `erase` destroyed the third element of the vector, and then the copy from the 4th element failed then the vector would be in a rather dangerous state -- the third element isn't a proper object any more. So the restriction in the standard does rather more than just define the runtime, it prevents this bad failure case.

Comment: If a copy assignment fails, can you really trust anything about the assignee then either?

Comment: @cHao: I suppose it depends on the programmer, but a minimal requirement is that after such failure the destination must be capable of being destructed without triggering undefined behavior. For maximum robustness the copy assignment operator would offer the "strong exception guarantee", meaning that if the copy throws then the destination is unmodified. Provided you can write a nothrow swap for your type, you can achieve this by first copying the source, then swapping the destination with the copy. None of which applies to `MyClass` of course, it can do nothrow assignment.

Comment: And yes, as a corollary those "rule of zero" people are writing classes whose copy assignment operators offer only the weak exception guarantee. At least, when they have two data members whose copies can fail, they are. This is often fine, since a caller who wants a strongly-safe operation can copy-and-swap for themselves, it just needs to be documented.